# getting the value from an NSDictionary of NSDictionaries

Tags: json, macos, ios5, nsdictionary

I am doing a native objC app. ios5
I want to parse a JSON file in the local bundle.
And read each item individually.
To follow is a sample of my JSON file, followed by the code I have working.
I also have explanation of what I think is going on, and the sample code that I need to get assistance with.  You are welcome to correct my interpretation as well.

=========================================================================

{"a":[
{"b":{"Q01":"A01","Q02":"B01","Q03":"C01","Q04":"D01","Q05":"E01","Q06":"X","C1":"NR","CABG":"NR","PCI":"NR"}},
{"b":{"Q01":"A01","Q02":"B01","Q03":"C01","Q04":"D01","Q05":"E02","Q06":"X","C1":"I","C1IND":"20","C1SCORE":"3","CABG":"NR","PCI":"NR"}},
{"b":{"Q01":"A01","Q02":"B01","Q03":"C01","Q04":"D01","Q05":"E03","Q06":"X","C1":"NR","CABG":"NR","PCI":"NR"}},
{"b":{"Q01":"A01","Q02":"B01","Q03":"C01","Q04":"D01","Q05":"E04","Q06":"X","C1":"NR","CABG":"NR","PCI":"NR"}},
{"b":{"Q01":"A01","Q02":"B01","Q03":"C01","Q04":"D01","Q05":"E05","Q06":"X","C1":"NR","CABG":"NR","PCI":"NR"}}

## ]}

## My code looks like:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nonacs" ofType:@"json"];    

NSError* error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];


if (jsonData) {

    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        // Handle Error and return
      return;
    }

    //NSArray *keys = [jsonObjects allKeys];    
    // not necessary becuase I know the Root key is a single "a"

    NSString* jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"]];


    tLabel01.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jsonData Length is = %d",  [jsonData length]]; 

    NSDictionary* dict01 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:jsonObjects];

    l2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dict01 length = %d", dict01.count];


    NSDictionary* dict02 =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict01];
    l3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dict2.length = %d", dict02.count];


    //NSArray* array01 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict01, nil];

    //NSArray *allvalues = [jsonObjects allValues];      
    //NSArray *allvalues = [[jsonObjects initWithContentsOf ] allValues];


    //l3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"allvalues.count = %d", allvalues.count];        

    //NSDictionary   *dictB = [dict01 objectForKey:@"b"]; 


    //l3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dictB.count = %d", dictB.count];

    l3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jsonObject count = %d", [[jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"] count]];
    //  this works really well...  except it returned 1700, and there should only be 1550

    //l4.text = @"nada";
    //[[jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"] count]]        

    NSArray *array = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"];
    NSArray *arrayVariable = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    //l4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q01 = %@", [arrayVariable  objectForKey: @"Q01"]];        

    //l4.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrayVariable count = %d", arrayVariable.count];

    NSArray *arrayb = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"b"];        
    l4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrayb count = %d", arrayb.count];





    bTV01.text = jsonString; 


    };
```

=============================================================================

The root Object is an NSDictionary with single Key "a".
The value corresponding to that value is an NSArray.
The array contains NSDictionaries with a single Key "b".
The B NSDictionaries contain another NSDictionary.

could someone show me the code to display the 3rd B NSDictionary value for "Q02"  please

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[[[root objectForKey:@"a"] valueForKey:@"b"] objectAtIndex:2]